# How to get autocomplete (GoCode) to work with all my imports?

Tags: eclipse, go, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, goclipse

After installing the GoCode autocompletion daemon in GoClipse, it works for the more general imports (fmt and such), but not for more specific ones.

I do believe my GoClipse is properly set up, since it works with some imports already.
The specific import I am trying to make it work for is "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim".

There must be something I have to do to make those imports work, but I haven't figured it out yet. I can always code without autocompletion, but eh.

Does anyone know how to make it work?
Thanks a bunch.

Note: I'd post images to illustrate my problem, but well: "You need at least 10 reputation to post images".

Edit : It also doesn't autocomplete local variables. Is it related? Or is it working as intended?

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add a comment with a link to your image, and someone can edit it into the question for you.

Comment: Here's the pictures I wanted.

https://i.imgur.com/YJYhavs.png Plugins setup

https://imgur.com/whUcbIj.png Clearly working for the most commonly used imports

https://imgur.com/67gz4tr.png But not for what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, So I digged and found the solution to my problem. I basically needed to locally install the import on my machine.

This is easily done with the go get command

For example, for the specific problem I had, I wanted the import "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim" to autocomplete.
I ran the command

> go get "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"

Restarted GoClipse and it works perfectly.

Hope it helps someone else.